# Is there a more efficient/proper way to write this in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I come from php and am just starting to cut my teeth in ruby and rails.

Is there more efficient or a more 'ruby' way of writing the following?

```
<% if !@user.twitter_url.empty? %>
    <a class="twitter" href="<%= @user.twitter_url %>">Twitter</a>
<% end %>
<% if !@user.facebook_url.empty? %>
    <a class="facebook" href="<%= @user.facebook_url %>">Facebook</a>
<% end %>
<% if !@user.google_plus_url.empty? %>
    <a class="googleplus" href="<%= @user.google_plus_url %>">Google Plus</a>
<% end %>
<% if !@user.linked_in_url.empty? %>
    <a class="linkedin" href="<%= @user.google_plus_url %>">Linked In</a>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way should be to use some Presenter or maybe a helper method. Anyway using metaprogramming you can do

```
<% [:twitter, :facebook, :google_plus, :linked_in].each do |social| %>
  <% unless @user.send("#{social}_url").blank? %>
    <a class="<%= social %>" href="<%= @user.send("#{social}_url") %>">social.to_s.titleize </a>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% [:twitter, :facebook, :google_plus, :linked_in].each do |social| %>
  <%= link_to(social.to_s.titleize , @user.send("#{social}_url"), class: social) unless @user.send("#{social}_url").blank? %>
<% end %>
```

Or even:

```
<% [:twitter, :facebook, :google_plus, :linked_in].each do |social| %>
  <%= link_to_unless @user.send("#{social}_url").blank?, social.to_s.titleize , @user.send("#{social}_url"), class: social %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

More compact way :

```
<%= link_to "Twitter", @user.twitter_url if !@user.twitter_url.blank?  %>
<%= link_to "Facebook", @user.facebook_url if !@user.facebook_url.blank?  %>
<%= link_to "Google Plus", @user.google_plus_url if !@user.google_plus_url.blank?  %>
<%= link_to "Linked In", @user.linked_in_url if !@user.linked_in_url.blank?  %>
```

With [present?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) instead, thanks to Mark Thomas comment :

```
<%= link_to "Twitter", @user.twitter_url if @user.twitter_url.present?  %>
<%= link_to "Facebook", @user.facebook_url if !@user.facebook_url.present?  %>
<%= link_to "Google Plus", @user.google_plus_url if !@user.google_plus_url.present?  %>
<%= link_to "Linked In", @user.linked_in_url if !@user.linked_in_url.present?  %>
```

Or you could use `unless` instead of `if !` with `blank?`, but I generally find code using unless hard to read, bu that's just me!

Comment: +1 except I'd use `if @user.twitter_url.present?` instead of negating the `blank?`

Comment: Correct, forgot there was present? in Rails!

Comment: Why is present? better? Looking at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F And showing the source) isn't it the same as blank? If its the same, wouldn't using the native blank? be faster? Or am I misunderstanding something (I am a ruby/rails noob after)

Comment: @JonathanW `present?` is the opposite of `blank?`. So you don't have to negate the condition when using the standard `blank?` if you want to test for the opposite. Better code readability this way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `blank?` instead of `empty?` here in case the url fields are nil. While `nil.blank?` is defined, `nil.empty?` is not.

```
<% unless @user.twitter_url.blank? %>
    <%= link_to "Twitter", @user.twitter_url, class: "twitter" %>
<% end %>
<% unless @user.facebook_url.blank? %>
    <%= link_to "Facebook", @user.facebook_url, class: "facebook" %>
<% end %>
<% unless @user.google_plus_url.blank? %>
    <%= link_to "Google Plus", @user.google_plus_url, class: "googleplus" %>
<% end %>
<% unless @user.linked_in_url.blank? %>
    <%= link_to "Linked In", @user.linked_in_url, class: "linkedin" %>
<% end %>
```